# How to invoke current instance method in template

Tags: groovy

I can do following to invoke meth:

```
class C {
    def methInInstance
    def m() {
        engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
        engine.createTemplate(new java.io.File('path/to/my.template'))).make(ins: this)
    }
}
```

And in `my.template`

```
<% ins.methInInstance %>
```

I hope invoke meth like following:

```
<% methInInstance %>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Errr... Both your examples are the same aren't they? Can you explain what you're trying to do, and the error you're getting?

Comment: @tim_yates sorry, I have edit my question